# How can a packaged electron app use a child_process?

Tags: php, node.js, electron, electron-packager

I wrote a part of an electron app already. In fact, I connected PHP to Electron using a child-process. (The code of the main.js file which does that can be found at the bottom of my question, to keep everything clear).

When I start my Electron application using

```
electron ./main.js
```

everything works woell: the PHP file executes properly. But, that's not what I want. I want to be able to pack my app, suing

```
electron-packager --electron-version=2.0.2 . --platform=win32 --arch=x64
```

The execution of that command gives no errors. Everything goes well and all the needed files are coppied to the subdirectory. But, when I execute the created .exe file, it doesn't show anything useful. Only a blank page.

Can somebody help me and give me some resources which could help me a little further? I already searched the web for a solution and I chatted over the Electron SLACK channel, but I didn't get an answer there. On the Slack it was because I wasn't quick enough to answer, since I was busy... And I didn't find anything helpful on the web.

I hope that someone here can give me some little tips, so that I can search in a better direction.

And now, as promised the code of the .main.js file:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');

let window;

function createWindow()
{
    const { execFile } = require('child_process');
    const child = execFile('php/php.exe', ['-S', '127.0.0.1:4911', '-t', 
    './www'], (error, stderr, stdout) => {
        if (error) { console.log(error); }
        if (stderr) { console.log(stderr); }
    });
    window = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    window.loadURL(url.format({
           pathname: 'localhost:4911',
        protocol: 'http:',
        slashes: true
    }));

    window.on('closed', () => {
                window = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('winow-all-closed', () => {
    if(process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if(window == null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

The contents of the ./www./index.php file, to where the child_process links is as follows:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

(Note: this file works wihtout packaging)

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, but decided to leave Electron for now.

Comment: Yes, I'm on the same path now...